# Effective web service connection management in vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wcf

Please I'm looking for an efficient way to manage web service connections in a wpf client application that I'm developing , currently I open the service connection on my client app for the duration that the app window is open until the user closes the application then I close the connection object,The user can make multiple service calls using that same object  ,however I still feel that this is not efficient ,any thoughts ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Why just not calling the service where it is need for that? Just consider using Keep-Alive to keep the HTTP connection.

Comment: R u saying that I can close the connection immediately after I make a call ? With the keep alive option

Comment: Yes, I would go into that direction.

Comment: I came across some articles that are  recommending using the channel factory approach to make the web service calls ,I'm studying it if it works great then I'll post my coding approach ,thx .

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim channel_factory As ChannelFactory(Of UnifyService.EnquiryServiceChannel)
  channel_factory = New ChannelFactory(Of UnifyService.EnquiryServiceChannel)("AccessPoint")
        'initialize secuirty credentials for the channel 
        channel_factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "uname"
        channel_factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "pword"
```

This is wrapped in a singleton class called WebServices 
The class also exposes a dispose connection code that is called when the main app window is closed .

```
    Public Sub disposeConnection()
    If channel_factory IsNot Nothing Then
        channel_factory.Close()
        If channel_factory.State = CommunicationState.Opened Then
            channel_factory.Abort()
        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

The class uses the same channel factory to make all service calls and deliver responses to the application .This does it for me , i am open to any further ideas or suggestions .Thank you.